# Convert varchar to timestamp on PostgreSQL: ERROR: "TZ"/"tz" not supported

Tags: postgresql

I have the following problem. I work on converting timestamps stored in a varchar column:

```
|    MyTimestamp               |
---------------------------------
|"Thu May 14 00:00:00 CEST 2009"|
|"Fri Aug 31 00:00:00 CEST 2007"|
```

with the [to_timestamp](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/functions-formatting.html) function:

```
 select 
    to_timestamp(myTimestamp, 'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TZ YYYY'
 FROM 
    my_table
```

but I keep getting:

```
ERROR:  "TZ"/"tz" not supported

********** Error **********

ERROR: "TZ"/"tz" not supported
SQL state: 0A000
```

I wonder what I did wrong, is there a better way to convert a varchar to timestamp? Does not PostgreSQL support TZ/tz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this syntax:

```
SELECT 'Fri Aug 31 00:00:00 CEST 2007'::timestamp
```

this would be

```
SELECT myTimestamp::timestamp FROM my_table
```